# Override Zurb Foundation 5 change Clearing default template globally

Tags: javascript, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to change the global template of the Clearing plugin (responsive lightbox gallery) but the documentation doesn't say anything about how to do it programatically; the `data-options` way is explained but nothing more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Looking into the code](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/blob/v5.2.2/js/foundation/foundation.clearing.js#L4) I've seen that there is actually a template in the `Foundation.libs.clearing...` namespace. After some tries I've arrived to this:

```
// Include scripts

// Change template
Foundation.libs.clearing.settings.templates.viewing = '' +
    '<a class="clearing-close">&times;</a>' +
    '<div class="visible-img" style="display: none"><div class="clearing-touch-label"></div><img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAD/ACwAAAAAAQABAAACADs%3D" alt="" />' +
    '<p class="clearing-caption"></p><a class="clearing-main-prev"><span></span></a>' +
    '<a class="clearing-main-next"><span></span></a></div>';

// Init
$(document).foundation();
```

It works, but I'm not sure if I can trust this as it's not documented... any better idea? Maybe there is an API for this...

Comment: I just wanted to add some extra text to the close 'X' link, and simply did: `$('a.clearing-close').prepend('Close ');`